# Play youtube videos in Totem movie player

Tags: totem, youtube

Whn I try to play  youtube video in Totem I get this error:

```
No supported stream was found. You might need to allow more transport protocols or may otherwise be missing the right GStreamer RTSP extension plugin.
```

[image]

I have all Totem plugins installed including

```
Plugins for the Totem media player
GStreamer coded installer
GStreamer extra plugins
```

Any idea?

Comment: we need more information: what exactly did you do to play the video? Did you download the youtube video and then opened the file? Or did you give an address like this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bOwyGYTMv8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bOwyGYTMv8)? Or did you use the youtube plugin?

Comment: @xubuntix Check the screenshot.

Comment: what happens if you open totem in a console? do you get another error?

Comment: How do you mean? Just start it from console and try to play youtube video, or start another instance after trying to play video? Which command?

Answer (score 1):

In Software Center:

- Look for "movie player"
- Select "Movie Player"
- Click on "More Info"
- Scroll down and check the "Add-ons" section
- Make sure that you have installed at least:

  - Plugins for the Totem media player
  - GStreamer coded installer
  - GStreamer extra plugins

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have all plugins installed. That's not the reason for this error. But thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: add that in the question.

Comment: i just reinstalled my system and what is really weird that before i did it totem played youtube videos. i knew that is not an implemented feature but one day i just pasted a link by mistake cause i thought i opened vlc and then realized that my totem can play youtube videos and i don't even know how the hell i did it. i fixed it by a mistake and i have no clue how, LOL.